# MMDetection SSD Training Error: ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/train.py", line 244, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/train.py", line 233, in main
    train_detector(
  File "/home/christ/dev/repos/railsight/mmdetection-2.25.3/mmdet/apis/train.py", line 244, in train_detector
    runner.run(data_loaders, cfg.workflow)
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmcv/runner/epoch_based_runner.py", line 130, in run
    epoch_runner(data_loaders[i], **kwargs)
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmcv/runner/epoch_based_runner.py", line 47, in train
    for i, data_batch in enumerate(self.data_loader):
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 368, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 314, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 965, in __init__
    self._reset(loader, first_iter=True)
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 996, in _reset
    self._try_put_index()
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1230, in _try_put_index
    index = self._next_index()
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in _next_index
    return next(self._sampler_iter)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py", line 226, in __iter__
    for idx in self.sampler:
  File "/home/christ/dev/repos/railsight/mmdetection-2.25.3/mmdet/datasets/samplers/group_sampler.py", line 36, in __iter__
    indices = np.concatenate(indices)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
  File "/home/christ/miniconda3/envs/mmdetection/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/signal_handling.py", line 66, in handler
    _error_if_any_worker_fails()
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 35413) is killed by signal: Terminated.
```

This is the error message I am faced with when trying to train using SSD with MMDetection. I have checked through my dataset and it works with faster_rcnn so I am not understanding why I am having such an issue with the SSD training. Any advice would be great!

```
_base_ = '../ssd/ssd300_coco.py'
dataset_type = 'CocoDataset'
classes = ('pantograph',)
data = dict(
    train=dict(
        img_prefix='configs/pantograph/train/',
        classes=classes,
        ann_file='configs/pantograph/train/SSDTrain.json',
        dataset=dict(
            ann_file='configs/pantograph/train/SSDTrain.json',
            img_prefix='configs/pantograph/train/')),
    val=dict(
        img_prefix='configs/pantograph/val/',
        classes=classes,
        ann_file='configs/pantograph/val/SSDVal.json'),
    test=dict(
        img_prefix='configs/pantograph/test/',
        classes=classes,
        ann_file='configs/pantograph/test/SSDTest.json'))
```

Above is my custom SSD config that I tried to run. I have double checked the file locations and made sure they are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

mmdet has a very good community, you can try to look at this [link](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/issues/9610) to solve your problem. Shortly, you should change your `classes = ('pantograph',)` as the following codes

```
cfg.metainfo = {
    'classes': ('balloon', ),
    'palette': [
        (220, 20, 60),
    ]
}
```